# Can a MAC laptop with thunderbolt 2 ports accomodate a Thunderbolt 3 dock from DELL?

Tags: mac, compatibility, thunderbolt, dock

I recently bought a DELL TB16 dock to use with my computer. I connect the thing using a thunderbolt 3 cable, and I get the internet, 2 screens my usb laptop plus power using only one cable. Works great, no problem.

It so happends that my girlfriend owns a MAC laptop (not sure which exactly) equipped with two thunderbolt 2. My question: would it be possible (using some kind of connector I guess) for her to connect to the dock using these? Even maybe at a "price" (for instance no power, or maybe only one external screen etc...)?

After a search, I am aware of similar questions having been asked arround the internet (like this one for instance: [Is Thunderbolt 2 forward-compatible to Thunderbolt 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088272/is-thunderbolt-2-forward-compatible-to-thunderbolt-3) ), but it seems to me that they do not address exactly the same question. In particular, I have a male thunderbolt 3, which I want to connect to a female thunderbolt 2 (and have them operate). Both devices can be assumed to come powered if needed (this is apparently a widespread caveat).

I hope my question is clear enough, feel free to ask for precisions.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: PS: I really don't want to get in a mac vs non-mac argument with anyone.

Comment: Thunderbolt is backwards compatible. However, by doing so your Thunderbolt dock will be limited to Thunderbolt 2 capabilities

Comment: Great. What would a possible connection look like though? I have litterally search the internet for an hour and I cant find a thunderbolt 2 male to thunderbolt 3 female adapter. On top of that, since I'm not an avid mac user myself, I have trouble anticipating whether the laptop will recognize the dock at all.

Comment: What do you mean what would the connection look like? You would use a Thunderbolt 3 cable.  Thunderbolt 3 is backwards compatible.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the backward compatibility when it comes to connecting TB3 dock / devices to a TB2 host. At least it seems that only cables / adapters for the other way round are available on the market.

Comment: Another sign is that even a TB3 to "full TB2" (i.e. not just miniDP for display) adapter is [bulky](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B019FPJDQ2/), which pretty much means the conversion is not as simple as one may think. (Probably because the signaling across a DP cable and that across a USB-C cable are quite different?)